# How to get the code coverage using squish coco of an HMI based on automated python test scripts

Tags: squish

We'll get the software in *.tgz format which we'll use to update the machine(HMI - Embedded system which we test). The *.tgz is complete software package.
We have python scripts which will test the application. 
My requirement is, I need to import this *.tgz file in to squish coco and run the python test scripts and identify which part of the software is untested.

Answer (score 0):

The way Squish Coco works is that you compile/build/generate the desired binaries/application with it, from the source code files of the binaries. The resulting binaries then have code coverage built into them.

Once such a binary has been started and its process finishes, the collected coverage information will be written to disk. (There is not even a way to disable this built-in functionality/mechanism for such instrumented binaries.)

So all you need is such instrumented binaries and can then exercise the application manually or via unit tests, GUI automation, etc.